# Paragraph Styling wont take in Custom CSS Manager but work in Developer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, styling, paragraphs

I was hoping someone could shed some light on why I'm unable to style all of the paragraphs within my site.

http://www.richclarkimages.co.uk/rich-clark

I'd like to force all Paragraphs and all H3 Titles to fit a 700px width, justify and centralise.

In developer I applied the following and see the result I'm after:

```
#content p, #content-sm p {
width: 700px;
text-align: justify;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
    }
```

In Custom CSS Manager I apply the same css but there is no change to the page? I wondered whether the CSS Editor had become unresponsive but tested other changes successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Rich

Comment: The way CSS works is that style declarations lower down the cascade trump style declarations higher up - and more specific style declarations trump less specific style declarations. So if any of your styles are not being adopted, either you are overwriting them lower down the cascade or you are not declaring them specifically enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should I expect then to see them visible but crossed out if they are being trumped?

Comment: If you write `p {width: 500px;}` but, higher up, you have already written `#content p {width: 700px;}`, then you should expect `#content p` to have a `700px` width. If you write `p {width: 500px;}` and further down the cascade you write `p {width: 300px;}`, you should expect `p` to have a `300px` width.

Comment: Your css doesn't seems to apply, using web inspector I don't see your rules. When you're talking about "custom css manager" is that an extension? Where exactly did you put your rules?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding !important to your #content p, #content-sm p styles in the custom manager css? (i.e., width: 700px !important; ) Your new styles may not rank high enough to override the developer styles.

Here is an older link to an article where you can read more: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: You shouldn't recommend to use `!important` as it's a bad programming practice.

Comment: Thanks Melinda I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @vard, I know it's bad programming (and try to avoid it); however, sometimes you do need to use it to get the desired effect.

Comment: Strongly advise against using `!important` - it's fine for development but not really appropriate for production.

Comment: @Rounin, I agree with you also but as I said before, it is sometimes necessary.

Comment: Alas it would not bring about the necessary changes. I applied it to each of the four lines but to no avail. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Rich Yes it's because your rules are just not added to any stylesheet you're actually loading. It seems to be a back office issue and not a front end one.

Comment: @Melinda I agree, there is edge cases where you can't work without an `!important` - dirty wordpress themes that add css as inline styles for instance. Though readers should always be warned that it should be avoided - as you surely know it's a bad practice the OP may not and keep using it in the future for not valid use cases.